# package react horizontal scrolling menu scrollnext and scrollprev doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, vite

i'm using package react horizontal scrolling, but arrowback and arrowforward for scrollnext and scrollprev doesn't work. i'm confused because it doesnt show any error on the console. i'm using "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu": "^5.0.1".

here's my code below v

```
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import BodyPart from "./BodyPart";
import { ScrollMenu, VisibilityContext } from "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu";
import "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu/dist/styles.css";
import { ArrowBack, ArrowForward } from "@mui/icons-material";
import "../../src/App.css";
import ExerciseCard from "./ExerciseCard";

const HorizontalScrollBar = ({ data, bodyPart, setBodyPart, isBodyParts }) => {
  function LeftArrow() {
    const { scrollPrev } = React.useContext(VisibilityContext);

    return (
      <ArrowBack onClick={() => scrollPrev()} cursor="pointer" sx={{ color: "#ff2625", position: "absolute", top: "30%", left: "0" }}>
        Left
      </ArrowBack>
    );
  }

  function RightArrow() {
    const { scrollNext } = React.useContext(VisibilityContext);

    return (
      <ArrowForward onClick={() => scrollNext()} cursor="pointer" sx={{ color: "#ff2625", position: "absolute", top: "30%", right: "0" }}>
        Right
      </ArrowForward>
    );
  }
  return (
    <ScrollMenu LeftArrow={LeftArrow} RightArrow={RightArrow}>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <Box key={item.id || item} m={"0 40px"}>
          {isBodyParts ? <BodyPart item={item} bodyPart={bodyPart} setBodyPart={setBodyPart} /> : <ExerciseCard exercise={item} />}
        </Box>
      ))}
    </ScrollMenu>
  );
};

export default HorizontalScrollBar;
```